# Rolling mean/centered moving average for a 3d numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, moving-average

I have a NumPy array with 8035 times, 43 latitude points and 43 longitude points. I need to calculate the moving averages of each point of this matrix in the 8035 times. My array has shape (8035,43,43).

```
def moving_average_centered(a,n):
    return pd.Series(a).rolling(window=n, center=True).mean().to_numpy()

mat = np.zeros([31390])

cont = 0
for i in range(len(b)):
    for j in range(len(b[i])):
        for k in range(len(b[i][j])):
            a=(moving_average_centered(b[i][j][k],11))
        mat[cont]=a
        cont = cont +1
```

My array just looks like NaN at the end. What could be the error in the code? I would like to have a NumPy array with shape (8035, 43, 43).

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to implement smoothing in 1D is with convolution. For example:

```py
import numpy as np

# Length of smoother.
N = 11

# Make some fake data.
data = np.random.random((8035, 43, 43))

# Make a smoothing kernel.
kernel = np.ones(N) / N

# Convolve the kernel along the first (time) axis.
out = np.apply_along_axis(np.convolve, axis=0, arr=data, v=kernel, mode='same')

# Check the shape.
out.shape
```

[`np.convolve()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.convolve.html) is a 1D function, so [`np.apply_along_axis()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.apply_along_axis.html) takes care of applying it along the time (first) axis of the data array. Both of these functions are very useful in signal processing with NumPy.

It sounds like there are probably some NaNs in your data. These are going to cause problems (e.g. spreading into the result when you convolve) so you may want to deal with them first.

If you want a different smoothing function (this kernel just takes the mean in the window), or you want to filter across more than one axis, then you should check the [`scipy.signal`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/signal.html) and [`scipy.ndimage`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/ndimage.html) modules, there are lots of filters in there. You won't need `np.apply_along_axis()` with those — most `scipy` functions are n-dimensional so you can tell it which axis to run along.

PS You almost never (like, seriously, never) need loops in NumPy (and when you loop in Python you don't need a counter). And 9 times out of 10 you don't need Pandas either. Keep it simple!

Comment: This is a great solution, but how could I do this by calculating the centered moving average? Calculating the centered moving average, the initial 5 points would be NaN and the final 5 as well.

Comment: You can control that aspect with the `mode` argument. I used `'same'` in the example to get the same shape output as input (per your question), but you can use `'full`' for a fully padded output, or `'valid'` for only the samples with complete suport in the kernel. If you want the NaNs you could use `np.pad()` to pad the output of a `'valid'` convolution.